# Dynamic selection by a vector in Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble `A` such:

| X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1_1 | x2_1 | x3_1 |
| x1_2 | x2_2 | x3_2 |
| x1_3 | x2_3 | x3_3 |
| x1_4 | x2_4 | x3_4 |

And a Vector `Y`: `(X2,X1,X3,X1...)`

I want to select into a single vector `B`: `(x2_1,x1_2,x3_3,x1_4...)` only the values in the table `A`, such the `B[n]` element it is selected within the column `Y[n]`.

I'd like to do this within a tidyverse pipeline, I want to avoid any `for` or `apply`.

I tried, after conversions of Y into integers referring to the position of the columns of A:

```
A %>% add_column(Y = Y) %>%
  mutate(B = .[,Y])
```

but it does not vectorize properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% 
   add_column(Y = Y) %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(B = cur_data()[[Y]]) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  X1    X2    X3    Y     B    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 x1_1  x2_1  x3_1  X2    x2_1 
2 x1_2  x2_2  x3_2  X1    x1_2 
3 x1_3  x2_3  x3_3  X3    x3_3 
4 x1_4  x2_4  x3_4  X1    x1_4
```

Or with `get`

```
A %>%
     mutate(Y = Y)  %>% 
     rowwise %>%
     mutate(B = get(Y)) %>% 
     ungroup
```

Or using a vectorized solution

```
A %>%
   mutate(B = .[cbind(row_number(), match(Y, names(.)))])
    X1   X2   X3    B
1 x1_1 x2_1 x3_1 x2_1
2 x1_2 x2_2 x3_2 x1_2
3 x1_3 x2_3 x3_3 x3_3
4 x1_4 x2_4 x3_4 x1_4
```

---

Or use a vectorized `row/column` indexing in `base R`

```
A$B <- A[cbind(seq_len(nrow(A)), match(Y, names(A)))]
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(X1 = c("x1_1", "x1_2", "x1_3", "x1_4"), X2 = c("x2_1", 
"x2_2", "x2_3", "x2_4"), X3 = c("x3_1", "x3_2", "x3_3", "x3_4"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Y <- c("X2", "X1", "X3", "X1")
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the function "cur_data()". I think it's a bit tricky to combine cur_data() and rowwise(), but I feel that this trick can make simple a lot of dynamic operation with pipelines!

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
A %>% add_column(Y = Y) %>%
  mutate(B = map2(Y, 1:n(), function(x, y){.[[x]][y]}))
```